# Error invoking HTTP Services from callbacks w/in a confirmation dialog

Tags: angular, callback, dialog, httpclient, typeerror

I'm working on an Angular (v7) application, and I'm getting a strange error when trying to invoke an HTTP service from a dialog component.

Rather than trying to explain my code arrangement, let me just show you the important parts

**My HttpService:**

```
export class HttpService {
   constructor(
      private _http: HttpClient
   ) { }

sendPost = (url, msg = {}, defTimeout = 30000, defRetries = 0) => {

  return this._http
     .post(url, msg, {
        headers: this.getHeaders(),
        observe: "response"
     })
 ...
```

**App Service Using My Http Service:**

```
export class CompanyProfileService {
   constructor(
      private httpService: HttpService,
      private env: EnvironmentService
   ) { }

   public setMyCompanyProfile$(msg: UpdateMessage) {
      let url = this.env.setCompanyProfileURL;
      let retVal = this.httpService.sendPost(url, msg)
      return retVal;
   }
```

The above method scheme works perfectly when I invoke them directly from my components. That is, I inject the app-specific service into my components, and I can invoke the methods just fine.

However, we have some use cases where before we do an update, we want the user to confirm their operation. For that, we've created (using the angular material dialog) a common wrapper/library that puts up a dialog, and then if the user selects "OK", the dialog completion invokes the service http method. Part of the data to this dialog was the name of the service function to invoke (e.g. setMyCompanyProfile$) and the message to send in the request.

Some our our earlier services where working using the above scheme, but then all of a sudden, we started getting run time errors in the console as shown below:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendPost' of undefined
at ConfirmComponent.push../src/app/services/company-profile.service.ts.CompanyProfileService.setMyCompanyProfile$ [as serviceFcn] (company-profile.service.ts:65)
at ConfirmComponent.push../src/app/services/confirm/confirm.component.ts.ConfirmComponent.onProceed (confirm.component.ts:50)
at Object.handleEvent (confirm.component.html:3)
at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
at core.js:21003
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
```

After carefully comparing the above situation that didn't work when invoked through the dialog with those that did work being invoked through the dialog, I discovered the only difference is the name of the variable I give to the injected HttpService.
When I use httpService, the sendPost method can not be found. When I use http, the sendPost method can be found.

**This signature on the constructor works:**

```
export class CompanyProfileService {
       constructor(
          private http: HttpService,
          private env: EnvironmentService
       ) { }**
```

**This signature on the constructor results in the error:**

```
export class CompanyProfileService {
   constructor(
      private httpService: HttpService,
      private env: EnvironmentService
   ) { }
```

Why would the name of a private variable matter?

Comment: are you sure that it returns the correct service when you change the name second this kind of issue usually is caused by dependency injection not having access to proper service so double check if the service is instantiated (for example add some consle logs to HttpService constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I put some console statements in my various components, and I think I figured out why it only works when the name "http" is used. I think this has to do with a scope and/or closure issue...

I should have designed this differently and used inheritance...

Lesson learned...